# Replace string with pattern keeping the string intact

Tags: shell, awk, sed

*Would to replace the string either with sed or awk, where it identifies a patter as mentioned below* :

**Example**: It looks for word starting with "XX" and ending with "XX" and replace the word with concatinating with "${hf:" at the start of "XX" and  "}" at the end of "XX"
    **INPUT**

```
CREATE TABLE XX_DB_XX.test_XX_YYYYMMDD_XX
AS
SELECT id
FROM XX_R_DB_XX.usr_XX_YYYYMMDD_XX
WHERE year              = XX_YYYY_XX
   AND month       = XX_MM_XX
   AND day         = XX_DD_XX;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
CREATE TABLE ${hf:XX_DB_XX}.test_${hf:XX_YYYYMMDD_XX}
AS
SELECT id
FROM ${hf:XX_R_DB_XX}.usr_${hf:XX_YYYYMMDD_XX}
WHERE year              = ${hf:XX_YYYY_XX}
   AND month       = ${hf:XX_MM_XX}
   AND day         = ${hf:XX_DD_XX};
```

Tried to replace the pattern matchin, but the issue is , in the output I want replace the $A , to the subsquet "XX_(*)_XX" string available over the input file.

```
 cat test.hql | gawk '{ print gensub(/XX_+[A-Z,_]+_XX/, "${hiveconf:$A}", 1) 
}' |  gawk '{ print gensub(/XX_+[A-Z]+_XX/, "${hiveconf:$A}", 1) }'
```

**OUTPUT: -> That I recived needs to be updated w.r.t the string available, So how can this be done:**

```
CREATE TABLE ${hiveconf:$A}.test_${hiveconf:$A}
AS
SELECT id
FROM ${hiveconf:$A}.usr_${hiveconf:$A}
WHERE year              = ${hiveconf:$A}
AND month       = ${hiveconf:$A}
AND day         = ${hiveconf:$A};
```

Comment: This is a description of code you want written for you (and for free), not a question. Please demonstrate what you have tried yourself, your results and how it differs from the desired output. Ideally, ask an actual question on a programming detail which got you stuck.

Comment: @Sampat, it is always nice to add your efforts too in your post as we all are here to learn, keep learning and keep sharing cheers :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Sorry forgot to add the trials that is done at my end, Have edited the question and added over the question

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 How can we do the reverse of the above string replacement from the above given "OUTPUT" file to "INPUT" file.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '{gsub(/XX_[a-zA-Z]+_XX/,"${hf:&}")} 1'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what `sed` exists for,

```
sed 's/XX[[:alnum:]_]*XX/${hf:&}/g' file
```

`[[:alnum:]_]` stands for Alpha numeric or underscore. The append `*` means zero or more times of it in regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do

```
sed 's/\(XX[^'XX']*XX\)/${hf:\1}/g'
```

in cases where there may be non alphanumeric characters as well in between the XXs.

First an `XX` is matched after which waits till an XX is found.